# How can I get an eventListener "keypress" to trigger links of my differents pages (student project)?

Tags: javascript

I"m working on a school project, so I have some limitations (rules).
I can just use basic html css and javascript.
No libraries.

I set up 5 pages (including the index), and i wanted to create some functions on an keyboard event, so the user can navigate between the 5 pages with keyboard 1 to 5 keys.

Here are my html and js code so far, i'm pretty sure the window location href is the problem here. It works, but its failing after 3 or 4 uses.

```js
function touche1(){
    console.log("touche 1 tapée");
    window.location.href = "../index.html"; 
}

function touche2(){
    console.log("touche 2 tapée");
    window.location.href = "./pages/projets.html";
}

function touche3(){
    console.log("touche 3 tapée");
    window.location.href = "./pages/presentation.html";     
}

function touche4(){
    console.log("touche 4 tapée");
    window.location.href = "./pages/medias.html";    
}

function touche5(){
    console.log("touche 5 tapée");
    window.location.href = "./pages/contact.html";     
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    var touche = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)
    switch(touche){
        case "1":
            touche1()
            break;
        case "2":
            touche2()
            break;
        case "3":
            touche3()
            break;
        case "4":
            touche4()
            break;
        case "5":
            touche5()
            break;
}})
```

```html
<nav>
    <a  href="../index.html">Accueil</a>
    <a  href="./projets.html">Projets</a>
    <a  href="./presentation.html">Présentation</a>
    <a  href="./medias.html">médias</a>
    <a  href="./contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a><br><br>
</nav>
```

I know it's linked to my pages url / window position href, but cant figure it out.

thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're most likely going to have to change from using `./` addresses and either fully qualify your addresses, or change them to use `/` so they start at the domain root, and qualify them from that point.  Once you are on `./page/contact.html` and you try to go to `./page/otherplace`, the url will try to go to `./page/page/otherplace` or something like that, due to the relative nature of `./`

Answer (score 0):

Try (open chrome console, run snippet and push keys 1-5)

```js
document.body.onkeypress = e => {
  let links = [
    'index.html',
    'pages/projets.html',
    'pages/presentation.html',
    'pages/medias.html',
    'pages/contact.html',
    ]
  location = links[e.key-1]||links[0];
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Accueil</a>
  <a href="pages/projets.html">Projets</a>
  <a href="pages/presentation.html">Présentation</a>
  <a href="pages/medias.html">médias</a>
  <a href="pages/contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a><br><br>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all ! I finally figured it out. 
My problem was my index was not in the same folder as my other pages. 
I just copied my index to be my home page and put it in the same folder, and kept my index as an enter page. It works fine.

Thanks for all the quick answers :)